# How can I simulate .fetchall() in Python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, tuples

This question might better be titled "How do I convert a list of dictionaries into a list of tuples," except I'm not 100% sure that's correct.

I am modifying a scraper I found online, which grabs data from a database using .fetchall().

```
cur.execute("SELECT num, location FROM table WHERE location='My Town';")
the_query = cur.fetchall()
```

The rest of the script thus expects `the_query` to be a list of tuples, which I *think* means `the_query` would look like this:

```
[(081143282, 'My Town'),(091338218, 'My Town')] ...
```

My modified version of this scraper must grab the data from a JSON feed, not from an sqlite database using fetchall. Using demjson.decode(), I end up with data like this:

```
[{u'num': u'081143282', u'location': u'My Town'}, {u'num': u'081143282', u'location': u'My Town'}]
```

Again, I *think* this is a list of dictionaries, but since I am still learning these different structures, I may be mistaken.

I have tried using .item() and zip(*) to convert the result of demjson.decode() into a list of tuples, but so far I can't make it work.

Can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list of dictionaries and get all the values from each of the dictionaries using `values()` function then convert them to tuples.

```
data = [{u'num': u'081143282', u'location': u'My Town'},
        {u'num': u'081143282', u'location': u'My Town'}]
print [(int(currentDict["num"]), currentDict["location"]) for currentDict in data]
```

**Output**

```
[(81143282, u'My Town'), (81143282, u'My Town')]
```

Comment: The earlier version of your answer might actually be better. In my specific use case, num is not always an int. But this seems to be working. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Kirkman14 But your expected output said `[(081143282, 'My Town'),(091338218, 'My Town')]`. Thats why I had to change.

Comment: Isn't using the `[0]values()` and `values()[1]` risky? I thought dictionaries were unordered, and best not to trust any order...

Answer (score 1):

First part of your problem, is that you have dictionaries (which are unordered) and you want to serialize those (in tuples). So you need a way of specifying with dictionary keys are being converted to what order.

```
tupleOrder = ('num', 'location')
```

Now that we have that, we need code that can convert a dictionary into something ordered:

```
def asSeries(aDictionary):
    return (aDictionary.get(key) for key in tupleOrder)
```

This will return a generator. To realize it as a tuple, we just use the tuple() function:

```
def asSeries(aDictionary):
    return tuple(aDictionary.get(key) for key in tupleOrder)
```

And now, if we want to flatten that all down to a one liner:

```
[tuple(dict.get(key) for key in tupleOrder) for dict in data]
```

You have some flexibility here. You can change your `tupleOrder` in one place, with named keys (instead of numbered indices). Want to use `list`s? Just replace `tuple()` with `list()`.